# Sometimes unauthorized, sometimes return response, with fetch in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I hope you can help me.

I'm doing a simple fetch hoping it gets executed before the DOM is rendered.

But, sometimes it returns a 401 answer for not being authorized, since the prop is undefined and sometimes it returns the correct answer.

Proposals?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        renderizado: false,
        token: props.token,
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
        const test = this.state.token;
        if(test !== undefined){
            fetch("url",
                {
                    headers: {
                        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + test,
                    },
                }
            ) 
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, renderizado: true }));
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("viene undefined");
        }
    }   

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.renderizado ? <h1>Cargado</h1> : null }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I've been in these for two days, I'm an amateur.

Thank you.

Comment: Please give the code for the component that uses this one. Right now we don't know how you implement this component. The `fetch` logic looks OK to me. Just to be safe: did you test the API on other services like Postman? Do they have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, postman return the correct response, and the component.

Comment: return (
<>
<ListInterviewers token={token} />
</>
)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (basically what I do is changing from `componentDidMount` to `componentDidUpdate`)

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    renderizado: false,
    token: props.token,
    data: null,
  };
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  const { token } = this.state;
  if (token) {
    fetch('url', {
      headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ data, renderizado: true }));
  } else {
    console.log('viene undefined');
  }
}

render() {
  const { renderizado, data } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      {renderizado ? (
        <h1>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}</pre>
        </h1>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i get the same response, sometimes yes and sometimes not :( 
But you gave me a better idea

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `if(test != undefined)`?

Comment: Yes, not work, i try some sentences, but i get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that is a Promise wich is not resolved yet and the component is mounted sometimes before.

Comment: I think that's the problem

Comment: try to make a async componentdidmount : async componentDidMount() {
    try
    {
      // await...
    }
    catch(error)
    {
  
    }
  }